# HP 2000 Laptop Touchpad Not Responding in Ubuntu and Windows ;External Mouse Works Fine

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, kernel, touchpad, synaptics

I'm facing a persistent issue with the touchpad on my HP 2000 laptop, which is dual-booted with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 7. The touchpad is unresponsive and doesn't register any clicks or touches, rendering it unusable. Interestingly, the touchpad issue is resolved temporarily when I ran Windows 7 in safe mode, but the problem eventually returned and isn't fixed by safe mode anymore.

The touchpad on my HP 2000 laptop is not responding in either Ubuntu 20.04 or Windows 7. I'm unable to use it for navigation or clicking. Strangely, an external mouse works perfectly fine. The issue initially got fixed once when I ran Windows 7 in safe mode, but this workaround is no longer effective. This leads me to believe that the problem might not be strictly hardware-related.
The problem persists even when Ubuntu is run as live on flash drive.

Some attached logs :

```
xinput list

WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:16              id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 lsusb
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0cf3:311d Qualcomm Atheros Communications Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c8:0222 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP Webcam-50
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0048 SiGma Micro Usb Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
 sudo lshw -C input
 
  *-usb                     
       description: Mouse
       product: SIGMACHIP Usb Mouse
       vendor: SIGMACHIP
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1.2
       logical name: input11
       logical name: /dev/input/event9
       logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
       version: 1.10
       capabilities: usb-1.10 usb
       configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=2Mbit/s
  *-input:0
       product: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
       physical id: 0
       logical name: input10
       logical name: /dev/input/event8
  *-input:1
       product: HDA Intel PCH Mic
       physical id: 1
       logical name: input8
       logical name: /dev/input/event6
  *-input:2
       product: HDA Intel PCH Headphone
       physical id: 2
       logical name: input9
       logical name: /dev/input/event7
  *-pnp00:03
       product: PnP device PNP0303
       physical id: 3
       capabilities: pnp
  *-input:0
       product: Lid Switch
       physical id: 1
       logical name: input0
       logical name: /dev/input/event0
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:1
       product: Power Button
       physical id: 2
       logical name: input1
       logical name: /dev/input/event1
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:2
       product: Power Button
       physical id: 3
       logical name: input2
       logical name: /dev/input/event2
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:3
       product: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
       physical id: 4
       logical name: input3
       logical name: /dev/input/event3
       logical name: input3::capslock
       logical name: input3::numlock
       logical name: input3::scrolllock
       capabilities: i8042
  *-input:4
       product: HP WMI hotkeys
       physical id: 5
       logical name: input6
       logical name: /dev/input/event4
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:5
       product: Video Bus
       physical id: 6
       logical name: input7
       logical name: /dev/input/event5
       capabilities: platform
```

```
 dmesg | tail
dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted
 sudo dmesg | tail
[ 6454.093801] RTL8208 Fast Ethernet r8169-0-100:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-100:00, irq=MAC)
[ 6454.386777] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eno1: Link is Down
[ 6456.897668] wlo1: authenticate with 34:71:46:02:58:3d
[ 6456.897715] wlo1: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
[ 6456.915966] wlo1: send auth to 34:71:46:02:58:3d (try 1/3)
[ 6456.918183] wlo1: authenticated
[ 6456.919826] wlo1: associate with 34:71:46:02:58:3d (try 1/3)
[ 6456.927508] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 34:71:46:02:58:3d (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[ 6456.927776] wlo1: associated
[ 6456.996206] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
```

Comment: Does the touchpad work if you disconnect the external mouse?

Comment: No;touchpad is not working after external mouse is disconnected. Infact it is not working at any instance whether with external mouse or without external mouse or after disconnecting external mouse.
But external mouse itself is working and currently i am doing scrolling and clicking with external mouse.

Comment: OK. Does it work when you're in the bios? Before booting an OS? This really sounds like a hardware issue and it only worked briefly because the hardware hadn't quite died yet.

Comment: In HP 2000, mouse/touchpad does not work in BIOS , only keyboard works but i did set BIOS to default but it has no effect , touchpad remains unresponsive, i suspect hardware issue but it recovered once in Windows safe mode and ran the entire session till shut down without any problem.